# What are these tiny black pest on chilli plant

Tags: identification, pests, peppers

They are really tiny and hard to focus on with a mobile camera. Are they good guys or bad guys? I don't think they are eating the leaves or the fruit, are they here for flower buds?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are aphids. Get your spray out and get rid of them quickly. I've had chilli plants and they're quite susceptible to these critters especially in dry climate and almost always after rainfall. Now you could either use a pesticide or buy a box of ladybugs or parasitic wasps and unleash them onto your plant. Also, it's best to get rid of them early on before they have a chance to multiply.

Comment: Most of the aphids magically disappeared. So these were causing yellowing of leaves of the plant?

Comment: Could very well be but then again, i do see a web in the second photo. Spider mites perhaps? Anyways, yes aphids can cause yellowing of the leaves. Even death of plants if left untreated. Over/under watering, too much or too little fertilizer, too small of a container are other reasons for leaves showing signs of stress. All these are bound to attract more aphids onto plants.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Aphids is correct... you can control with just soap and water, or you can go to an organic like neem oil, pyrethrum, or spinosad; those will probably require less attention... use something that is available and legal in your jurisdiction.

Comment: Thanks! I picked them off as there were barely any aphids left.